# How to restore deleted Git branches

Tags: git

How to restore deleted branches.

I've made "git push --prune" and seems that nearly all branches were deleted remotly.
Please help me!!

Comment: They will be deleted, if they don't have a local counterpart (cf. manpage). To recreate them, you have to push them again to the remote repository: `git push origin <sha of branch>:<branchname>`. I don't think there's a way to automatically recover all previous branches …

Comment: If you're lucky, the branches might still be locally stored under the `remotes/origin/*` namespace. Can you check that? (`git branch -r`)

Comment: Branches are not there, checked using "git branch -r".

Comment: If you have access to another checkout of the repo (i.e. one of your coworker's checkouts), the deleted branches should still be there (use `git branch --list --no-abbrev -r --no-color -v`), and you can put them back with `git push origin <commitid>:refs/heads/<old branch name>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use git reflog. reflog helps you in these scenarios. See The link below for further information:

http://blag.ahax.de/post/421939327/recovering-a-deleted-branch-using-git-reflog

Comment: It seems that it is only for commits restoring, when I make "git reflog" I cannot find anything about deleted branches.

Comment: A branch is only a pointer to a certain commit. So it's the same (at least code-wise) to check out a branch or the HEAD commit of this branch.